# error message "Ambiguous reference to member ‘TableView(_:numberOfRowsSection)"

Tags: uiviewcontroller, tableview

I have a `UIViewController` of which I embedded a `UITableView` into it.

At the ViewController I created :

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

I then link it in IB by dragging this  property to the `tableView`.

Then I link back the delegate and protocol to the `ViewController`.

But the error message “**Ambiguous reference to member ‘TableView(_:numberOfRowsSection)** kept reappearing.

I believe the solution should be quite easy but I really cannot get it. 
What has gone wrong?

code :

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class BG006bViewControllerMain: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

Note :numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAt  - all these no problem.

### added on 29 Dec 2019 : Adding the following in the hope that it will make my question clearer and also in response to comments received :

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class BG006bTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate  {

var BG006b: [BGTest006bClass] = []

var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<BGTest006bClass>!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
   // super.viewDidLoad()

            // 2) Declare an instance variable for fetch resule controller
                    // let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<BGTest006bClass> = BG006b.fetchRequest()
                    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<BGTest006bClass> = BGTest006bClass.fetchRequest()


                // 3) Deploy Standdard codes
                               let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name1", ascending: true)
                               fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

                       if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                           let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                           //Initialize the fetchResultController
                           fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(
                                   fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                   managedObjectContext: context,
                                   sectionNameKeyPath:nil, cacheName: nil)
                           fetchResultController.delegate = self

                           do{
                               try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                               if let fetchedObjects = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects{
                                  BG006b = fetchedObjects
                               }
                           } catch {
                               print(error)
                           }
                       }
            }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return BG006b.count
}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

```
     let cellIdentifier = "BGTest006b"

     //let cell = tableView.dequeuReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BG006bTableViewCell

     cell.name1_Label.text = BG006b[indexPath.row].name1
     cell.name2_Label.text = BG006b[indexPath.row].name2
     cell.name3_Label.text = BG006b[indexPath.row].name3
     return cell
}
```

problems begins here :

```
// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods

import UIKit

import CoreData

class BG006bTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate  {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>){
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    } **error - Ambiguous.......**

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?){

        switch type {
        case .insert:
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade) **error - Ambiguous.......**
            }
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            } **error - Ambiguous.......**
        case .update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } **error - Ambiguous.......**


        default:
            tableView.reloadData()
        } **error - Ambiguous.......**


        if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects{
            BG006b = fetchedObjects as! [BGTest006bClass]
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } **error - Ambiguous.......**
```

Comment: Since the error references `numberOfRowsSection`, maybe you should include that code in your question.

Comment: Hi How do I include the code here? I tried editing the question but I dun think this is the right way. I am quite new to StackOverflow so really groping my way around. Apologies and thanks.